# PDO parameterized query with a LIKE statement in Cloud SQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, pdo, google-cloud-sql

When I run this query in Google Cloud Shell it works fine and returns 5 rows of data as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE Address LIKE '%123 Queen%' LIMIT 5;
```

But when I pass in the same search term `123 Queen` to this parameterized PDO query it does not return any results:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE Address LIKE :term LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute(array(':term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this work? `$stmt->execute(array(':term' => '%123 Queen%'));`

Comment: Thanks @SeanBright, yes I am calling `$stmt->fetch()` later in the code:   `$array = array();
  foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) AS $x) {
       $array[] = $x;
  }`

Comment: I tried using `$stmt->execute(array(':term' => '%123 Queen%'));` but still get no results.

Comment: Your syntax looks fine, so my other thought would be that maybe your manual test and PHP-based one are using different databases, but I dunno.

Comment: @SeanBright, your first comment was correct.  Turns out there was nothing wrong with either my original syntax, or your suggested test.  Both worked as expected once I used the correct variable name in my `json_encode` statement.  That was my mistake.  Thanks for your help guiding me to the answer.

Comment: @DanielAttard, can you write an answer with your solution so it appears as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: `SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE Address LIKE CONCAT('%',:term,'%') LIMIT 5`

Comment: Thanks @Kubwimana Adrien.  I tried your suggestion of `CONCAT('%',:term,'%')` but it did not work.  I believe that your suggestion is equivalent to `'%'.$_GET['term'].'%'`.

Comment: I think it's your value binding that's not right. look into bindValue() and try to use '?' for placeholders if you can. I use it all the time and I haven't had any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

My original question asked why this parameterized PDO query did not return any records:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE Address LIKE :term LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute(array(':term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

$array = array();
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) AS $x) {
   $array[] = $x;
}
```

As it turns out, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the above code.  My error was that I was referencing the wrong variable name in the `json_encode` statement below.  I mistakenly referred to `array`, when I should have referred to `$array` like this:

```
$array = $array ?: array('Not Found');
echo json_encode($array);
```

I am providing this answer at the request of @LundinCast.